# How to make For loop wait for Firebase Database response?

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a function that receives an object array. The array looks like this:

```
var receivedObjects = [{nuih329hs: 100}, {8suwhd73h: 500}, {2dsd73ud: 50}, {9u238ds: 200}];
```

Each key is an ID, and each value is a number.
The objects are in a set order and what I want to do is iterate through the objects and define each value as a variable, which I'll then use when creating a html row.

The problem I'm having is, I have to make a call to a Firebase database inside this iteration code, the result is that while a row is successfully being created for each object value, the value entered into each row is always the same (the last/most recent value in the object array), so in the above case the number `200` is appearing in all four rows.

I think this might be happening because maybe all the iterations are completing before the first Firebase call is even completed, meaning the variable `currentValue` (which I'm entering into the rows) is set at the last value in the array before the first Firebase call is made.

Note: There is another array (called `listOfIds`) which contains Firebase IDs, I'm able to successfully use each ID from this array as a variable to use in the Firebase call, `var currentID` is that variable.

This is the function:

```
function populateTable(receivedObjects){

   var receivedObjectsLength = receivedObjects.length;
   // Note: an object array called listOfIds exists here (containing Firebase IDs to be used for querying Firebase), it's referenced below.

   for (var i = 0; i < receivedObjectsLength; i++) {

      // listOfIds is an Object array 
      var currentID = Object.keys(listOfIds[i]);

      var term = (Object.keys(receivedObjects[i])[0]);
      var currentValue = receivedObjects[i][term];

      //The following line is showing the correct ID and Value for each iteration:
      console.log("The current ID is: "+currentID+" and the current value is: "+currentValue);

      firebase.database().ref('/users/' + currentID).once('value').then(function(child) {

      // This is where the rows are created, ``currentValue`` is used here, but it's appearing as the same value in every row.

      // The next line is showing the correct current ID, but it's showing the currentValue as "200" in every row.
      console.log("The current ID is: "+currentID+" and the current value is: "+currentValue);

    });
  }
}
```

I'm very confused, because I thought the Javascript iteration code would wait until the data gets returned from the Firebase call, but it seems this isn't the case? How can I change my code so that the line `console.log("The current ID is: "+currentID+" and the current value is: "+currentValue);` inside the Firebase call success function will show the correct `currentValue`?

Comment: For another example of returning promises out of the function, see the answer I just wrote up here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42346560/how-do-i-make-a-function-return-data-that-was-set-within-function-child-snapsho/42347920#42347920.

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen , that looks interesting, is there a performance difference between the two methods, or would they both be about equal?

Comment: The dominant factor for performance will be the amount of data you read/write. If that's the same between them, any other differences are likely to be inconsequential.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of making the loop wait, you can use a function to put `currentID` and `currentValue` into their own scope so that they don't get overwritten with each iteration:

```
function getUser(currentID, currentValue) {
    return firebase.database().ref('/users/' + currentID).once('value').then(function(child) {
        console.log("The current ID is: "+currentID+" and the current value is: "+currentValue);
    });
}
```

In your loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < receivedObjectsLength; i++) {
    ...
    getUser(currentID, currentValue)
}
```

Comment: it worked , but i wonder is it a correct way to do in async ??