# How do I make a function return data that was set within function (child snapshot) in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to return data to function that calls a function with firebase code, because of the asynchronous and nested structure of firebase queries it is not able to return values, I intend to use this logic to set tool tips in chart.js

Here is my code:

```
window.onload = function() {
    get_data();
}

function get_data() {
    var data = get_val();
    console.log("...." + data);
}

function get_val() {
    var label = "10/2/2017";
    var Name = localStorage.getItem("VName");
    console.log("Name:::" + Name);
    var at_val;
    var dbref = new Firebase("https://apraisalstaging.firebaseio.com/EmployeeDB/EInfo/");
    dbref.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(childsnapshot) {
            var data = childsnapshot.val();
            var Nameval = data.Name;
            if (Nameval == Name) {
                console.log("Success");
                Ikey = childsnapshot.key();
                console.log("Key:::" + Ikey);
                var dxRef = new Firebase("https://apraisalstaging.firebaseio.com/EmployeeDB/EApraise/" + Ikey);
                dxRef.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
                    snapshot.forEach(function(childsnapshot) {
                        var data = childsnapshot.val();
                        console.log(data);
                        if (label == data.Dateval) {
                            console.log("-------> bingo");
                            at_val = data.Attitude;
                            console.log("got value:" + at_val);
                        }
                    });
                }).then(function() {
                    console.log("In then:" + at_val);
                    return at_val;
                });
            }
        })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data is loaded from the Firebase Database asynchronously. You cannot return a value *now* that hasn't been loaded yet. And until the `async` and `await` keywords are commonplace, you cannot make JavaScript wait for the async value.

The closest you can get today is to return a promise from `get_val()`. Then your calling code will be:

```
get_val().then(function(data) {
  console.log("...." + data);
});
```

To do this you'll have to implement `get_val()` as:

```
function get_val() {
  var label = "10/2/2017";
  var Name = localStorage.getItem("VName") || "delta";
  console.log("Name:::" + Name);
  var at_val;
  var dbref = firebase.database().ref("EmployeeDB/EInfo/").orderByChild("Name").equalTo(Name);
  return dbref.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
    var promises = [];
    snapshot.forEach(function(childsnapshot) {
      var data = childsnapshot.val();
      var Nameval = data.Name;
      Ikey = childsnapshot.key;
      var dxRef = firebase.database().ref("EmployeeDB/EApraise/" + Ikey).orderByChild("Dateval").equalTo(label);
      promises.push(
        dxRef.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
          snapshot.forEach(function(childsnapshot) {
            var data = childsnapshot.val();
            at_val = data.Attitude;
          });
        }).then(function() {
          console.log("In then:" + at_val);
          return at_val;
        })
      );
    })
    return Promise.all(promises);
  })
}
```

I made a few changes to `get_val()`:

- it uses the new 3.x versions of the Firebase SDK. The solution could also work with 2.x, I just didn't feel like setting up a jsbin for that.
- it populates a list of promises, one for each of the `EApraise` records
- it returns a promise that resolves when all the `EApraise` records are loaded.
- it uses Firebase queries to find the correct record. This removes the need for checking the values in the `then()` callbacks. But more importantly it ensures that only the necessary data is downloaded.

To make that last point true, you need to add a few index definitions to the rules in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/rules/):

```
{
  "rules": {
    "EmployeeDB": {
      "EInfo": {
          ".indexOn": "Name"
      }
      "EApraise": {
        "$eid": {
          ".indexOn": "Dateval"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here a jsbin with the working code: http://jsbin.com/jawamilawo/edit?js,console

Comment: great solution!

Comment: this method and syntax is quite difficult to include in tooltip callbacks with chart.js are any workarounds possible

Comment: this code is returning an object what changes need to be made for it to return a variable,right now its displaying object[promise] as the tooltip

Comment: That seems like a different problem. But if you put the function in a separate script file, you can just include the function invocation in the tooltip.